# Register new images with URLs

Tags: eclipse, url, resources, rcp

I am trying to register programatically generated images using an specific URL at `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen`, but at the moment I have not found a mechanism to do this.

Anyone could give me some advice about the possibility of performing my desired behaviour?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can register an image in the workbench shared images in `preWindowOpen` using:

```java
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

IWorkbenchConfigurer config = getWindowConfigurer().getWorkbenchConfigurer();

config.declareImage("id for image", desc, true);
```

Comment: Will that work if I reference the image through an URL in the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point?

Comment: There is nowhere in the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point where you can specify a URL so I don't understand what you are asking. Perhaps you need to explain much more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. My purpose is to add a toolbar with commands whose icons will be generated on the fly. More in detail, depending on the screen resolution, I want to use icons of different sizes.